# Are templated arguments passed by const ref optimized to be passed by value when small enough?

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing

When a standard function takes in a templated argument without modifying it, it seems it always takes in a `const ref` (ex: [std::vector::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)).

Does this mean that the function for something like a `bool` argument will become `std::vector<bool>::insert(const bool& value)` ?

Or is there some optimization that makes it into `std::vector<bool>::insert(bool value)` instead ? If yes, will my own template functions benefit from it as well ?

Comment: why would that be an optimization?

Comment: Isn't it better to pass a bool by value rather than reference ? (from what I understand, passing by reference means passing the address of the variable, of a size of 8 bits for instance, versus the size 1 bool)

Comment: `bool` is 1 byte. btw `std::vector<bool>` is the best example of how trying to optimize `bool` to one bit can go wrong

Comment: When the call is inlined (which is the case for vector template) it does not matter - compiler performs the same optimizations with const refs to primitive types.

Comment: Functions like that are likely to be inlined, so nothing is physically passed. When it's not inlined, it is generally not possible to make such optimisations.

Comment: Arguments to functions are in typical ABIs passed in registers when it's possible. There is no difference to pass a 1-byte argument then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` is a template and thus `std::vector<bool>::insert()` is by definition `inline`.

Modern compilers easily "see through" references in `inline` calls and optimize them all out.

For small objects like `int` there would be no difference between passing by-reference and by-value.

Example:

```
struct A {
    int func1(const int& x) { return x + 1; }
    int func2(int y) { return y + 1; }
};

int func1(int x) {
    A a;
    return a.func1(x);
}

int func2(int y) {
    A a;
    return a.func2(y);
}
```

Generated code ([godbolt link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GjczGY)):

```
func1(int):                              # @func1(int)
        lea     eax, [rdi + 1]
        ret
func2(int):                              # @func2(int)
        lea     eax, [rdi + 1]
        ret
```

If you're exposing an API via a shared library, *then* passing by-reference may incur an extra dereference. That's because in the C++ ABI passing by-reference actually happens via a pointer. But for `inline` calls this is generally not an issue.

On the other hand, passing a *large* object by-value might not be easily optimizable if copying or using it involves side effects. So for a generic template, passing by-reference is a smart design choice.